# Trying to loop axios requests and push it asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, axios

```
async function getData() {
  let getProject =
    await axios.get('url', {
      auth: {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'pw'
      }
    })

  let projects = await getProject.data.value;
  let arr = []

  projects.map(project => {
    let item = axios.get(`url`, {
      auth: {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'pw'
      }
    })

    arr.push(item)
    console.log('arr', arr)
  })

  let result = await axios.all(arr)

  console.log('pr', result)

  return arr;
}
```

In the `getProject` I get the object of the projects by calling the API. Then I try to loop through these fetched objects and use unique url for each project to call another API in `projects.map`.

`console.log('arr', arr)` gives me the array of Promises, and some of them are failed requests and some of them are successful. This is intended because some projects might not have the valid API. But I will want an array with successful Promises.

This doesn't even reach the line `console.log('pr' result)` and I am not sure why.

Am I doing it right?

Comment: if you're not getting to the final console.log, are you getting any warnings/errors in the log? such as an uncaught promise error? Make sure the console is showing warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try revising your code so that `arr` is an array of functions that return promises for axio requests (rather than `arr` being an array of actual axios request promises, as you are currently doing):

```
let projects = await getProject.data.value;

// Map all project items to functions that return promises
let arr = projects.map(project => {

    // Return a function that returns a promise
    return function() {     

        // Returns a promise for GET request
        return axios.get(`url`, {
            auth: {
                username: 'username',
                password: 'pw'
            }
            })
    } 
})

// Axios.all will concurrently perform all GET requests 
// in arr (ie the mapping of projects to functions that
// return promises from axios.get )
let result = await axios.all(arr)

// Should print results from axio.get (if all requests successful)
console.log('pr', result)
```

This is a subtlty with the way methods like `axios.all` typically work and is similar to the native `Promise.all` method. For more information see the example just above "axios API" [in the axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#user-content-axios-api)

Comment: I follwed the way you told me, the `arr` contains bunch of `f item()` and not the result that I want. How do I have to use these? I do `let result = await axios.all(arr)` at the end, but still the same.

Comment: Hi there, please see updated answer above - does this work for you?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Thanks!